# How can a function returning bool and having two int arguments be called without its arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I am using std::sort to sort an array in descending order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define size 5
using namespace std;

bool descending(int x,int y){
    return x>y;
} 
int main(){
    int a[size]={5,3,7,34,2};
    sort(a,a+size,descending);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works. But I'm not sure why.

1. Shouldn't descending be called with 2 arguments?

Comment: `template< class RandomIt, class Compare > void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );` expects function pointer of type `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`. refer: [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: @TruthSeeker it doesn't necessarily have to be a function pointer. Any callable object would do.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are not calling `descending()` function in your program, you are passing it to `std::sort()` as a [function pointer](https://denniskubes.com/2013/03/22/basics-of-function-pointers-in-c/) which accepts a function pointer of type

```cpp
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

as its third argument.

---

according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) , the third argument to std::sort is `comp` which is

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.
> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:

> `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`

> While the signature does not need to have const &, the function must not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all values of type (possibly const) Type1 and Type2 regardless of value category (thus, Type1 & is not allowed, nor is Type1 unless for Type1 a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11)).

> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​

#### source :

[std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Why isn't `Type1` allowed unless for `Type1` a move is equivalent to a copy?

Answer (score 1):

On this line `sort(a,a+size,descending);` the function `descending` is not being called at all. It is being **passed** to the function `sort`. The function `sort` will call `descending` and it will use two arguments (which it will get from the array `a`).

The take-away is that there are two things you can do with a function:

- You can call it
- a function has a value (its address), which you can pass as a parameter to another function, save in a variable, etc.

There are a few technical details here which I've skipped over. For instance, what is actually being passed in your case is a pointer to the function. But the essential idea is that functions are callable but they are also values that can be passed around just like other values.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

> Shouldn't descending be called with 2 arguments?

No, because you don't call it. You give it to `std::sort`, which will then call it, passing it elements from the array as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` uses iterators. This means that when comparing, it dereferences the pointer to compare the actual value. This is what it looks like (when comparing, Reference: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)),

```cpp
if(comp(*(it + n), *it)) { ... }
```

Once the pointer is dereferenced, in this case `int` pointers, it gives the `int` value which the iterator points to. This is why passing in `bool descending(int x,int y)` as the comparator method works without an issue.